# Issue involving columns with the same name

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to create a view in C# involving two separate tables, where one field has the same name in both tables. Changing the column names is not possible, nor is creating new names for the columns just for the view. This is because the data cannot be modified in any way. I have been presented with the following error:

> Column names in each view or function must be unique. 
> Column name 'Child_ID' in view or function 'Testing' is specified more than once.

An online search has revealed that this is because all columns must be unique. However, when I tried adding the respective table name before each offending column, the error was still returned. Is there any way to get around this? I simply cannot change the column names.

Comment: A "view" in c# is very vague. Show some code please.

Comment: Even if you could have two columns called `Child_ID` in one view - and you already know that you can't - what do you think the query `SELECT Child_ID FROM dbo.MyView` should return? One column (which one?), two columns (in which order?) or something else? Even at a very abstract level it's hard to see how this could possibly work.

Comment: @Pondlife - Usually specifying the respective table name within square brackets before the field would work in a normal select statement. I was hoping that it would be the case here too

Comment: @DotNET no, that is not possible. A query does not need to store metadata, but a view does. When the view stores metadata, it needs to define *unique* column names.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @AaronBertrand. Workaround time it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if `Child_ID` has the same value in both tables (I assume this is from a join), then you simply leave one of them out. What is the point of returning both?

If `Child_ID` has *different* values, then first off I question whether they should be called the same thing, but assuming there is a reason for this, use an alias.

```
SELECT 
  Child_ID_FromTable1 = Table1.Child_ID, 
  Child_ID_FromTable2 = Table2.Child_ID
...
```

Your query builder needs to recognize the case when multiple tables have the same column name, and either:

1. automatically assign aliases in some pre-determined way (as I showed above, this wouldn't be difficult to do);
2. force the user to select an alias for one or both columns; or,
3. force the user to pick one or the other to remove from the output list.

Comment: Aliases aren't really an option unfortunately. Is it possible to query a view with the original non-alias values?

Comment: @DotNET sorry I do not follow your question. As Tim said, *something* has to deal with the problem - there is no magic here. Either your query builder has to leave duplicate columns out, or it has to assign aliases.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use column [Aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179300%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

```
SELECT T1.Child_ID AS T1ChildID, T2.Child_ID AS T2ChildID,...
```

Comment: I cannot use aliases, as my C# application is a query builder which accepts any database as input. Thus how would users be able to query with aliases?

Comment: Then your C# app must deal with the problem. A query builder has to ensure that all column names are unique.

Comment: Is it possible to query a view with the original non-alias values?

Comment: For example - `SELECT Child_ID FROM View_Name` , while the view has set up an alias for "Child_ID".

Comment: @DotNET no, that is not possible. Of course you could always try it, but you'll get an invalid column name. Why would you *want* your query builder to be lazy like this? What is the end user going to do with two columns called `Child_ID`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - The problem is that users may be using a database where one table would have a column called "id" and another table would have a column also called "id" for example. Now the user may use my application to create a view for these two respective tables so that their compound join may be "saved" and used for sub-select purposes. Thus when a view would be queried, it would actually be queried with the real column names

Comment: @DotNET So when your query builder discovers duplicate column names, force the user to assign an alias to one or both before even trying to save the view. Done.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I have considered this approach, however this would cause problems in the long run. Since views represent "virtual tables" which have been joined together, other tables can also be merged alongside them. On doing so, the other tables would not be aware of the aliases within these views. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong as I might have not completely grasped the concept of views

Comment: @DotNET you can *always* check the set of columns that are exposed by an existing view - just look at `sys.columns` for that `object_id`. You're making this much harder than it has to be - SQL Server stores all this metadata specifically so that it (and you) can look it up later. It doesn't really matter what underlying column the exposed column name references, it just matters that you can check new columns against the existing set for more collisions. I'd be curious to see how you plan to merge those changes...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Could you kindly elaborate on your last point?

Comment: @DotNET not sure I know how to. Quite frankly, and don't take this the wrong way, but if you're building a query builder that builds views, and you don't quite grasp the concept of views, you may want to consider hiring some expert help.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - This is University work, not an option :) Thanks for the input though.